# Dynamic forms aren't being marked as submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have an ng-repeat that contains forms:

```
<form name="wrapperForm">
  <div ng-repeat="thing in things track by $index">
    <ng-form name="myForm{{$index}}">
      <input type="text" ng-model="thing.name" required />
      <span ng-show="myForm{{$index}}.$submitted">Form submitted!</span>
      <button type="button" ng-click="doSubmit($index)" />
    </ng-form>
  </div>
</form>
```

**In Controller**

```
$scope.doSubmit = function(index) {
  var form = $scope.wrapperForm['myForm' + index];
  form.$setSubmitted();
}
```

For whatever reason, `$setSubmitted` doesn't do anything and doesn't change the form's `$submitted` property.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong.  I have a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1Xcbs4S9qopVkVb0tvI?p=preview) based on your example.  I'm using `form.$invalid` but it's the same idea.  I can't reproduce your error.  Please include more details.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - the difference is that your error is showing when it's invalid, I'm showing when the form has been `$submitted`

Comment: It's the same idea.  A proof a concept.  You'll then have to submit the forms, and the message should show the same way.  There is nothing wrong with your current syntax.  Other than the fact that you aren't ever actually submitting the forms in the code you provided.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Made the requisite edits - the problem is that the form never gets $submitted set to true.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this.  Once I properly closed the `<button>` element it all worked.  I updated the plunker from my previous comment.